# Detecting directories with "directory?" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to detects directories im my computers.but when I write below code , Ruby just give me "." and "..".

```
Dir.foreach("c:/windows") do |i|
   puts i if File.directory(i)
end
```

please help me.
thanks

Comment: It listed the current directory `.` and the previous directory shortcuts `..`, but nothing else. Are you sure the system you're on is able to read the C:/ partition correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dir.foreach` returns only the filename (relative) , so it won't work. Build the absolute path or better try a simple:

```
Dir['c:/windows/*/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, except `File.directory(i)` should be `File.directory?(i)`

```
Dir.foreach("/mnt/tmp") do |i|
   puts i if File.directory?(i)
end
=>
.
..
majic
Dropbox
```

Comment: Are you sure? `if -d i` is not even valid Ruby.

Comment: not sure at all now as i've tried it. hmm, i'm almost certain i've used -f -e -d etc with files, but maybe i've been coding in perl

Comment: (previous comment was referring to earlier version of answer)

Answer (score 0):

It is also the part of the directory. To move up folder. 
So need a conditions in the each file of the directory to remove those two files.